# Where can I read old English text with new English explanations

Tags: british-english, history, early-modern-english, old-english

I like old English like "Coole their heeles", "thee" ,"thy" ,"ye" etc.

Where can I find old English text but with explanations and meaning?

I would also like to read old text, can you list them too, like top 100 classical English texts. Will be a big plus if available on Project Gutenberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Old English*, also known as *Anglo-Saxon*, is the term that describes English up to the first half of the eleventh century and it has to be learnt more or less as a foreign language. The sort of English you’re referring to is, I suspect, *Early Modern English*. This is much more accessible. Gutenberg will almost certainly have what you’re looking for. For more recent texts, you might also find [The Victorian Literary Studies Archive](http://victorian.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/index.html) of some interest.

Comment: you are a literati, you must have a "must read books" list. would you please consider sharing.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: If you're interested in the English language, I have some reading suggestions on my blog here: http://realgrammar.posterous.com/pages/references

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: *a literati*?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: OP seems to have been careful in not capitalizing *old* and *new*.

Comment: @Kris oops. _embarrassed_. a literate. never used it beyond _someone who is able to read and write_ till now.

Answer (score 2):

Back in school, we had an edition of Beowulf like that.  The original text on one side, and modern English on the other side.  Probably you can find such an edition if you look.  I did some Google, and found this:

> Beowulf: A New Verse Translation
>   translated by Seamus Heaney
>   This highly-praised bilingual edition offers the Old English text side-by-side with Heaney's rendition. Less flowery than older versions, Heaney's translation nevertheless manages to capture the power of the ancient epic, yet makes for a quick and exciting read. Winner of the Whitbread Award.